# IIS: Can't access my site

Tags: iis, firewall

I have Windows 7 Professional. With IIS 7 or 7.5 I have set up a little website. So far all works fine on http://Localhost:80 - I can see the site.

Then I set up the firewall so port 80 is open. My Router routes TCP:80 to my pc. But from my second pc I cant access the site. I can ping the other pc but why I can't access the page through the LAN?

Please help!

Comment: I turned my firewal off.... both pcs... but it doesnt helped where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to access the site via "localhost/sitename" or "machinename/sitename"?

If you're trying to access localhost on another machine it will be trying to resolve the url locally.

Answer (score 0):

nonono =) I actually access the site via http:\localipPC1:80 from pc2 on pc2 i access it http:\localhost:80 and it works (i know that the 80 is not needed)
on the server machine  I run netstat -an

```
  Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              listen
```

so I think the port seems to be correkt isn't it?

Comment: apparently Markus "didnt set the incoming rule for port 80 only outgoing"